# We can't remove article from a singular countable noun. So is that a noun modifier or complement?

Tags: nouns, articles, modifiers, complements

We can't remove **article** from a singular countable noun. So is that a noun **modifier** or **complement**?

We generally call it a modifier though it's mandatory...But why?

Comment: No: we don't normally call articles 'modifiers'. The function of articles as dependents in NP structure is **determiner**.

Comment: So, Adjective is a modifier. According to this, Can't we make **determiner** as a part of **adjectives**? Cause , a lot of people say that determiners are a part of adjectives...

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your preferred set of terminology. Huddleston & Pullum (2002) say that determiners are *neither* complements *nor* modifiers (p. 24); instead, they're a special type of dependent occurring only in noun phrases.

Comment: I have seen the NP in a DP called a complement of the determiner. https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~beatrice/syntax-textbook/ch5.html

Comment: People throw terminology around a lot. Part of it is confusion and part of it is group marking, and one should always ask for definitions and tests.

Answer (score 0):

Determinative and adjective are distinct word categories.

Determinatives most often function as determiner in NP structure, but some can also function as modifier in AdjP structure.

Compare:

> [1] *That film was great*.
>
> [2] *The film wasn't that great.*

In both examples "that" is a determinative.

In [1] it's functioning as determiner of the noun "film", while in [2] it's functioning as modifier of the adjective "great".

Note that 'determin**ative**' is the word class (POS) while determin**er** is the corresponding function. Notice the slightly different spellings.

Comment: Now I am more confused about **determinatives** and **determiners**. And isn't "**that**" modifying the noun "**film**?

Comment: No: as I said before, in [1] "that" is functioning as a determiner, and in [2] it's functioning as a ''modifier'.  'Determinative' is a part of speech (like noun, adjective etc.) and 'determiner' is a function (like subject, object etc.).

Comment: So,  **functions** are subject, object, **determiner**, verb, complement, modifiers

Comment: @SalimUddin Yes, except that "verb" is a part of speech. not a function. Its usual function is 'predicator'.

Comment: One should also note that while these terms are increasingly common, they are a recent innovation by (or popularised by) Huddleston and Pullman. The use of "determinative" instead of "determiner" makes logical sense, but not all books on grammar use the words like this.

Comment: One interesting analysis (I don't have the reference to hand though) is that the head word in a NP is not the noun but the determinative.  And hence these should be called Determinative phrases. The Noun in a "DP" complements the determiner.  (oh I see Tim mentioned the same in another comment)